Why vs-code doesn't hit my breakpoint in my api?
When I try to debug a simple Golang program like this, it works
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    var name string
    name = "Adan"
    fmt.Println(name)
}

but in my Go api, breakpoints not hitting
look, guys, this is my main function, where I configure my server
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
...
)

var (
    menuRepo       psqlrepo.MenuRepository   = psqlrepo.NewMenuRepository()
    menuService    service.MenuService       = service.NewMenuService(menuRepo)
    menuController controller.MenuController = controller.NewMenuController(menuService)

    dishRepo       psqlrepo.DishRepo         = psqlrepo.NewDishRepo()
    dishService    service.DishService       = service.NewDishService(dishRepo)
    dishController controller.DishController = controller.NewDishController(dishService)

    httpRouter router.Router = router.NewMuxRouter()
)

func main() {
    if err := godotenv.Load(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    httpRouter.POST("/api/menu/{id}", menuController.Create, middleware.ValidateToken)
    httpRouter.POST("/api/dish/{menu_id}", dishController.CreateDish, middleware.ValidateToken)
    httpRouter.SERVE(os.Getenv("PORT"))
}


And here is my repository where I set a breakpoint, I have the breakpoint in the first if statement of the function insertOptionAvailable
package psqlrepo

func insertOptionAvailable(optionAvailable entity.OptionsAvailables, optionID int, _db *sqlx.DB) error {
    var (
        itExist bool
    )
    if err := _db.QueryRow("select exists (select 1 from optionsAvailabe where name = $1)", optionAvailable.Name).Scan(&itExist); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if itExist {
        return errors.New("this item already exists")
    }
    optionAvailable.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    optionAvailable.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
    _, err := _db.Exec("insert into optionsAvailabe(name, quantity, extra_price, option_id, updated_at, created_at) values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)", optionAvailable.Name, optionAvailable.Quantity, optionAvailable.ExtraPrice, optionID, optionAvailable.UpdatedAt, optionAvailable.CreatedAt)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}


func (*dishRepo) NewDish(dish entity.Dish, menuId int) (sql.Result, error) {
    var (
        _db        = db.NewPostgreSQLConection()
        itExist    bool
        dishID     int
        extraItems []entity.ExtraItem
    )
    defer _db.Close()
    if err := _db.QueryRow("select exists (select 1 from dishes where name=$1)", &dish.Name).Scan(&itExist); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if itExist {
        return nil, errors.New("dish already exists")
    }
    dish.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    dish.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
    err := _db.QueryRow("insert into dishes(name, description, tags, menu_id, price, created_at, updated_at) values($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) returning id", dish.Name, dish.Description, dish.Tags, menuId, dish.Price, dish.CreatedAt, dish.UpdatedAt).Scan(&dishID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(*dish.Ingredients) > 0 {
        for _, ingredient := range *dish.Ingredients {
            if err := insertIngredient(ingredient, dishID, _db); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

        }
    }
    if len(*dish.Extras) > 0 {
        for _, option := range *dish.Extras {
            optionID, err := insertOption(option, dishID, _db)
            if err != nil || optionID == -1 {
                return nil, err
            }
            extraItems = append(extraItems, option.ExtraItems...)
            if len(extraItems) > 0 {
                for _, _optionAvailable := range extraItems {
                    if err = insertOptionAvailable(_optionAvailable, optionID, _db); err != nil {
                        return nil, err
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil, nil
}


Here is the service where I call repo
package service

import (
    "database/sql"

    ...
)

type DishService interface {
    NewDish(dish entity.Dish, menuId int) (sql.Result, error)
}

var (
    _dishRepo psqlrepo.DishRepo
)

type dishService struct{}

func NewDishService(dishRepo psqlrepo.DishRepo) DishService {
    _dishRepo = dishRepo
    return &dishService{}
}
func (*dishService) NewDish(dish entity.Dish, menuId int) (sql.Result, error) {
    return _dishRepo.NewDish(dish, menuId)
}


and here the controller
package controller

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    ...
)

type DishController interface {
    CreateDish(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
}
type dishController struct{}

var (
    _dishService service.DishService
)

func NewDishController(dishService service.DishService) DishController {
    _dishService = dishService
    return &dishController{}
}
func (*dishController) CreateDish(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.Header.Set("Content Type", "json/application")
    var (
        dish     entity.Dish
        response entity.Reponse
        vars     = mux.Vars(r)
    )
    menuID := vars["menu_id"]
    if menuID == "" {
        http.Error(rw, "menu id required", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(menuID)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(rw, "error with menu id", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&dish); err != nil {
        http.Error(rw, "Error getting body", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    result, err := _dishService.NewDish(dish, id)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(rw, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    response = entity.Reponse{
        Message: "Dish created successfully",
        Error:   "",
        Data:    result,
    }
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(&response)
}


and in postman when I send the post request to http://localhost:8080/api/dish/13 the program run well but the breakpoint doest hitting.
I try to set a several configurations on my lunch.json file, at this point I have this and none of them works for me:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "local",
            "processId": 0
        },
    ]
}

I also ensure if I installed go and vs-code for Macs with apple silicon, mine is an m2 MacBook air, so I installed the correct versions.

Where exactly are you setting a breakpoint ? Please also provide the CreateDishcontroller implementation.

@xflr6 I call my repo in a service and then the service in my DishController where I make all the validations before I pass all the data to the repo, and is in my repo where I have a breapoint. I run the debugger and the program runs and save data in database but it doesn't stop on my break point

Have you verified that len(*dish.Extras) > 0 and len(extraItems) > 0? (if these are not true then your break point will not be reached). I'd suggest adding a log.Println where you are setting the breakpoint to confirm the code is actually run. Note that you don't need the if len(x)>0 before the for range (if the slice is entry then the loop will just be skipped anyway).

Yes, everything is running well, I set a print and it works, but I don't know why don't stop in breakpoint.

Unfortunately this is going to be difficult to answer (as we cannot replicate your setup). Can you try adding a breakpoint in main (check if it's triggered when the app starts), is that works try dishController.CreateDish and keep working your way down until it does not trigger.

it doesn't work, I don't know what happened, it used to work when I set a breakpoint in main, but now it doesn't work. Maybe using another IDE. Imma try another one.

OK, so to clarify - debugging works in a new project, but does not work in this specific project? That being the case try resetting the launch.json to the defaults, if no luck then there are troubleshooting instructions (adding the results of these steps, especially logs, will make it more likely you will get an answer here).

I had problems with VSCode and go debugger on mac, if the project directory is a link create by ´ln –s …ˋ
Starting VsCode in the original directory worked
